# Unit testing mongoose model with Chai and Mocha

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, tdd, chai

I am trying to run the unit testing on my Nodejs application using Mocha and Chai. I am using Mongodb with Mongoose Framework. Here is my student.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var studentsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: String,
    phone: Number,
    address: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});


var Students = mongoose.model('Student', studentsSchema);


module.exports = Students;
```

And this is my student.model.test.js

```
let assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Students = require('../models/students.model');

describe ('Student',function(){

    before(function (done) {
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongoose_basics');
        const db = mongoose.connection;
        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
        db.once('open', function() {
          console.log('We are connected to test database!');
          done();
        });
      });

    it('student works!',function(){
        var s = new Students({name:'krishna'});

        s.save(err => {
            if(err) { return done(); }
            throw new Error('Should generate error!');
          });

    });
    after(function(done){
        mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(){
          mongoose.connection.close(done);
        });
      });

});
```

I want to run the unit test using Mocha and Chai. When I run `mocha student.model.test.js` I am getting following error

```
TypeError: Students is not a constructor
```

I am not sure why it's returning not a constructor.

Comment: You're the only person who can check what `Students` is in your case. From the code above, I'd expect it to be constructor function. The only problem I see is that it should be `var studentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(...)`, not `var studentsSchema = mongoose.Schema(...)`, but I'm not sure how it can contribute to the problem.

Comment: According to mongoose doc it should be  ``var studentsSchema = mongoose.Schema(...)``  not ``var studentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(...)`` with out new  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/

Comment: It seems the only place in documentation where they used it without `new`. It's a constructor. Any way, it's unlikely that it can cause the error you have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that is require statement are importing only the function related with your model so if you want to get the model try this follow statement:

```js
var Students = require('../models/students.model').Students;
```

or